# Rain detector in minecraft with commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to know is there a way to detect if it is raining, but purely with commands (/stats, /testfor, any possible way, hit me I can take it), without the use of cauldrons, soil, fire blocks, etc. They all are too unreliable. I need it to be instant since I want to perform constant actions while it rains and stop immediately when it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried to create this yourself yet? If so, you should edit that into the question.

Comment: Have you checked the [official wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands) list for any commands that could have any relation to your problem/inquiry?

Answer (score 6):

Didn't find any designs online after searching for like an hour and now found the solution after thinking about it for 10 minutes.

If someone needs that kind of a detector: I'm testing the `{Fire:}` NBT tag on armor stands.

[image]

Forgot to add that armor stands are being spawned with NBT tag `{Fire:32767,Invulnerable:1}` with no blocks above them. 32767 is not the value needed, it could be any value from 2 and above, and when you should test for a value 1 smaller then what you choose, I just used it while testing different idea earlier.

The comparator outputs a redstone signal when it is not raining very accurately and turns off when it starts raining.

**Edit: /testfor actually does output a signal, for some reason it didn't when I was testing, so you don't need the kill command block at the end.**

Comment: Could you edit the commands into the answer for less experienced users to "catch the thread"? If you do so, don't forget to use code blocks (command on a new line with 4 spaces preceeding it), or for parts of commands, place backticks - \`\` - on `both sides` of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could place down an observer facing a fire atop of a nether wart. whenever the rain extinguishes the fire, the observer will activate a redstone signal from its back. If you lead the signal trough two command blocks(one to set weather and the other to place back the fire) the rain will disappear, and problem solved.
Note that the rain needs access to the fire, and you would probably need to do this in many chunks since weather varies from spot to spot.

Comment: using mods you could copy and paste the creation, allowing you to save time

Comment: doFireTick is set to false on my server, thats why **I specified that I can't use it**.