# Is there a way to detect rain in datapacks? [Minecraft 1.16]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[The answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299566/rain-detector-in-minecraft-with-commands) technically works when utilizing command blocks, but isn't possible when working with datapacks. I do have the same limitations as the linked question, in that I can't use cauldrons, soil, and so on to detect it.

What I'm attempting to do is make it rain infinitely, but I don't want it to continuously run the command. Yes, I can set up commands so that `load.json` runs it on server (re)load, but the maximum time I can set that to is roughly 11 days. Since I'm making a datapack that is intended for survival world use, I need this to be continuous and run again if it's no longer raining.

Comment: Your actual issue is that you don't want to run a command as often? Then use `/schedule`. Also, the fire solution doesn't require command blocks, only commands. That works the same in functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you turn weather off in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20519/can-you-turn-weather-off-in-minecraft) (see answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to detect when it's raining to do that. Simply set the **doWeatherCycle** gamerule to false and run `/weather rain` in your function (the one that's registered in load.json). When the weather cycle gamerule is true, the weather can change naturally. When it's false, it can only be changed with commands.